# Recycleview pagination not bind adapter android

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

Hello friends i want to integrate pagination in my recycleview so below is my code

**in onCreateVIew**

```
  LinearLayoutManager  mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.task_recycle);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
 mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                if (OnzupApplication.mPendingDatas.size() < total) {
                    page++;
                    new getPendingTask(false,true).execute();

                }
            }

        });

if (mAllMethods.check_Internet() == true) {
        new getPendingTask(true,false).execute();
    } else {
        mAllMethods.ShowDialog(getActivity(), "", getString(R.string.net_not_available), "OK");
    }
```

**Call AsyncTask**

```
    public class getPendingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private boolean showLoading;
    boolean pagination;

    public getPendingTask(boolean showLoading,boolean page) {
        this.showLoading = showLoading;
        this.pagination=page;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (showLoading == true) {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", getString(R.string.loading));

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        mGetPendigTask = (GetAllPendigTask) mPostParseGet.getPendingTask(mGetPendigTask, token, page);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (showLoading == true) {
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        try {
            if (mPostParseGet.isNetError) {
                mAllMethods.ShowNoConnectionDialog(mActivity, mContext, "", getString(R.string.net_not_available), getString(R.string.setting), getString(R.string.cancel));
            } else if (mPostParseGet.isOtherError) {
                if (!mPostParseGet.isRequestTimeOutError) {
                    new ActivityHelper(mActivity).sendMail(token);
                }
                mAllMethods.ShowDialog(mActivity, "", getString(R.string.data_not_found), "OK");
            } else {
                if (mGetPendigTask.isSuccess() == true) {
                    mPendingDatas = getData();


                    total = Integer.parseInt(mGetPendigTask.getTotalitems());

                    if (mGetPendigTask.getTasks().size() > 0) {
                        mTextViewNoData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mAllPendingRecyclerAdapter = new AllPendingRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), OnzupApplication.mPendingDatas);
                        if (pagination==false)
                        {
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAllPendingRecyclerAdapter);
                        }
                        mAllPendingRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        mTextViewNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When i call above code 1 page is loaded but when i scroll second page data is not loaded any idea how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line

```
 mAllPendingRecyclerAdapter = new AllPendingRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), OnzupApplication.mPendingDatas);
```

You did create the Adapter at the first time, when you use load more function in recyclerview. You should add your data in your own Adapter instead of create the new one